# Multiple values for aria-describedby when using jQuery Validation Unobtrusive

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I am using the latest version of jQuery Validation Unobtrusive in combination with the latest version of jQuery Validate. The validation itself works like a charm. However if the field is invalid, values will be added to the `aria-describedby` attribute.

Let's say I want to type in my password (for validation the length of the password must be greater than 6). The initial HTML looks like this:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-minlength="The field Passwort must be a string or array type with      a minimum length of '6'." 
   data-val-minlength-min="6" data-val-required="The Passwort field is required." 
   id="Password" name="Password" tabindex="2" 
type="password">
```

I start to type a password with only 5 characters and then remove focus from the `input` by clicking somewhere on the `body`. The validation runs through and a bunch of attributes and values including `aria-describedby` will be added. Now the `aria-describedby` attribute only has a single value `Password-error`. If I then focus the input field again and remove all characters and even keep pressing backspace, a new value on each keyup is added. This results in the following:

```
<input data-val="true" 
   data-val-minlength="The field Passwort must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '6'." 
   data-val-minlength-min="6" 
   data-val-required="The Passwort field is required." 
   id="Password" name="Password" tabindex="2" type="password" aria-required="true" 
   aria-invalid="true" class="input-validation-error" 
   aria-describedby="Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error Password-error 
Password-error">
```

This is quite an overhead of values for the attribute considiering that the values are equal. Is this behaviour usual or does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: See my answer below. Somehow the problem was gone after I rebuild the solution in VS and deleted the shadow copies which get created in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no explicit explanation for the problem but since Visual Studio creates shadow copies in the background I could solve the issue by clearing the cashe and deleting all shadow files for the project and a rebuild afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

This issue was present in v1.13.0 of jquery.validate.js but has since been fixed (in at least v1.14.0).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with version 1.19.5, where `aria-describedby` attributes were added in many inputs for no reason. The reason, in my case, was having a validation element with no corresponding input element of the same name. It looked like `JQuery.validation` just got confused. The OP has already accepted an answer, yet I thought of sharing a potential fix for scenarios similar to my case.